# Collection and content

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, collections, jvm

I read the following about collections and the overheads around them.
Since i do not have  a computer science background,would appreciate if someone got through this in a little more depth for a layman to pick up:

In a typical 8-character string on a 32-bit platform,25% is the data and 75% is the JVM overhead(Understandably).
It would need 96 characters for overhead to be 20% or less - this is the part I could not understand.
It is probably hinting at longer strings being more efficient(and the same for collections).
How is it?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the meaning of the sentence. The meaning is that if `8` characters account for `25%` of the total memory occupied by a string then it means that the overhead is roughly `24` bytes.

So in a `96` characters string you have that overhead is

```
24 / (24+96) = 20%
```

So a longer string is not more efficient in absolute terms, it is more efficient in the sense that the overhead, which is fixed regardless of string length, has less impact in percent to the total memory occupied compared to a shorter string.